# Tem como mostrar os milésimos do segundo em Script VBS?

Tags: windows, vbscript

Preciso disso pra medir tempo em fraçao de segundos no arquivo **hora.vbs**

```
Dim CmdTime 
CmdTime = now()
msgbox CmdTime
```

no Exemplo acima mostra somente a data completa com hora minutos e até o segundos, sem mostrar os milésimos do segundos.

Answer (score -3):

Neste exemplo se obtém os milésimo, mas a programação está em C#, em vbs eu não conheço como faz:

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 7, 16, 8, 32, 45, 180);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("fff"));
```

Resultado:
180

retirado de:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values